# Relativistic speed and quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light

Just a thought experiment. First we entangle two particles, and then send one of them on a space journey, make it travel really fast. First we synchronize the 
watches, of course. So, after some time we measure some property of a particle (no matter which). WHEN will the other particle be affected? Because the clocks are showing different times. 
Sorry if I oversimplified this question, and sorry for my English!

Comment: Interesting question. I think you might want to look at relativistic density matrices for more information. here is an example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4027.pdf which talks about relativistic entanglement (I have not read it yet though)